# Debugging directory and files creation in Xcode

Tags: xcode, file, debugging, directory, save

I used

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
```

to save files and create some directories in the app. Is it possible to view these files and directories in the debugger? Like after I reached a breakpoint I can view the app's Document folder. The only possible solution I can think of is mass-NSLogging with various `NSFileManager` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh never mind I've found it. Go to Organizer -> Devices -> Click your device -> Applications -> Click your app

And the folders will be populated below. It's not automatically updating though, you have to click to other places and back to view updated results.